# how to make a subshell a "program"

Tags: shell, environment-variables, subshell

I want to ignore all pre-existing env variables, and echo just one, like this:

```
env -i <(
   export foo=bar; 
   env
)
```

and this would just print:

```
foo=bar
```

however, the construct of

```
env -i <()
```

doesn't seem valid even though my intuition says it should be valid.
How do I make an inline program here for env -i to execute?

Answer (score 3):

Give env an actual program:

```bash
env -i bash -c '
   export foo=bar
   env
'
```

Note that since that also removes the `$PATH` environment variable, if `bash` is not in the system's default command search path, that won't work.

You can look-up the path of the `bash` interpreter before passing to `env` with:

```
env -i -- "$(command -v bash)" -c '
   export foo=bar
   env
'
```

And the `bash` shell you start may have the same kind of problem in finding an `env` command.

Comment: sure but because it just needs a file to run (not a program perse), so I would think a file descriptor like this: `env -i <(echo foo)` would work, but perhaps env -i doesn't work with fd's like that?

Comment: this didn't work for me, did you test it? which version of bash?

Comment: @AlexanderMills, in which way does it not work for you?

Comment: @AlexanderMills, `env` executes files. The expansion of `<(echo foo)` on Linux or Cygwin is a magic symlink to a pipe and on other systems a device file, you can't execute pipes/devices, you can execute a shell interpreter such as /bin/bash, and you can tell a shell to interpret code read from a pipe or passed as argument like with -c here.

Comment: env doesn't just execute files, it simply writes to stdout if not given any args. It should be able to handle a temp FD or whatever is generated by `<()`, it's 2023. The code in OP is pretty I wish it worked lol

Comment: @AlexanderMills I did test it. "it doesn't work" is the worst possible request for help. Exactly what happens?

Comment: I am on /bin/zsh on a new mac, I get extraneous env vars, like:

`foo=bar SHLVL=1 _=/usr/bin/env'

which makes me suspect other env vars could sneak in too..
I am having absolutely zero fun formmating this comment. Do you see the 2 extraneous env vars that I just mentioned?

Comment: I do. Those are set by the shell. Other programs may set their own env vars. For example `env -i foo=bar perl -E 'while (($k,$v) = each %ENV) {say "$k=$v"}'` outputs the "foo" variable and a "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING" variable (for me). "SHLVL" and "_" are set by zsh. For me, I also see "HOME", "LOGNAME", "PWD" and "OLDPWD" (although I can't understand why PWD and OLDPWD need to be exported)

Answer (score 1):

If the point is to run commands in a subshell where all variables have been unexported, in zsh you can do:

```
(
  typeset +x -m '*'
  those-commands
)
```

Note that like many other shells, zsh automatically passes the `_` environment variable with the path of the file being executed as value to the commands it executes.

That `typeset +x -m '*'` will only unexport the shell variables that have the `x` flag on. Environment variables that zsh received on startup and that can't be mapped to shell variables (such as some with names like `123`, or newline or `***`...) or that zsh doesn't import from the environment (such as `$IFS`, `$USERNAME`) will still be passed along in the environment of the commands it executes.

```
$ env '123=x' '***=bar' 'IFS=xyz' zsh
$ (typeset +x -m '*'; env)
_=/usr/bin/env
IFS=xyz
123=x
***=bar
```